# Looking for specific black and white videos on measure theory

Tags: measure-theory, reference-request, lebesgue-measure, lecture-notes

I am looking for a playlist of very nice videos on measure theory. I remember they were from MIT, but I can't find them now. They were short but quite insightful and fun to watch.

Comment: Does this count as a reference-request?

Comment: I guess it does, thanks for pointing out.